# Simplify: $2w(z^2+1)=2z(w^2+1)$, $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to simplify:

$$2w(z^2+1)=2z(w^2+1), z,w \in \mathbb{C}$$

Simplifies to:

$$2wz^2-2zw^2+2w-2z=0$$

But doesn't seem like it would form a nice quadratic function.

Any tips?

---

Would it be valid to merely square root the whole (the first equation) thing?

Comment: Try factorizing this equation.

Answer (score 1):

Divide by $2$ and factor out $(w - z)$:

$$2wz^2-2zw^2+2w-2z=0$$

$$\iff 2(wz^2-zw^2+w-z)=0$$

$$\iff wz^2-zw^2+w-z=0$$
$$\iff (w - z) (wz + 1)=0$$

$$\iff w - z = 0 \lor wz + 1 =0$$

$$\iff w  = z \lor w  = -{1\over z} $$

Comment: So is $z=w$ the only solution? Or $z=-w^{-1}$ as well?

Comment: @mavavilj Yes, I edited my answer

Comment: I think the $z=-w^{-1}$ might be rejected. The original equation is equivalent to $\frac{z}{2}+\frac{1}{2z}=\frac{w}{2}+\frac{1}{2w}$ $\iff$
$\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z}-w-\frac{1}{w})=0$, which does not solve by plugging in $z=-w^{-1}$.

Comment: @mavavilj If you plug in $w=-z^{-1}$, the left-hand side becomes $-2z-z^{-1}$, and the right-hand side becomes $-2z^{-1}-2z$.